# Windows 7 - How to generate CSR when IIS is not installed

Tags: windows-7, ssl, csr

My .NET application will be communicating with a third party server application that is implemnted as web-service over SSL. This application will run from different flavours of Windows 7 platform. The server application requires me to generate CSR file. The only way I can find generating a CSR is via IIS but this may not necessarily be installed on all computer where my application will be hosted. Any ideas on how can I generate a CSR on Win 7 platform without using IIS?

Comment: Both answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186368/314104 http://stackoverflow.com/a/6469640/314104 are drastically better answers than http://stackoverflow.com/a/6468801/314104 (which is marked as accepted).

Comment: Heroku gives a good overview of how to generate a CSR with OpenSSL - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/acquiring-an-ssl-certificate#generate-private-key

Answer (score 34):

For a more recent version of openssl...
https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html links to 
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries which links to 
http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html which has links for win64 and win32 openssl.

Otherwise, you should be able to install openssl v0.98h on windows with this:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

Run the openssl at the command prompt (Start->Run->"cmd.exe"):
`openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key`
or you can use this online tool to generate the openssl command:
https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm

When you run the `openssl req` command on your computer, it will generate a CSR (with public key embedded) and private key.

Comment: In my windows install it was openssl.exe, but otherwise that all worked great. I already had openssl installed for work with SSH. Thanks velcrow!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to generate CSRs from code and you are using some of .NET languages, use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) or our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php). They both support certificate requests in PKCS#10 format. For C++ you can probably use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Digicert has an easy to use tool for managing certificates on Windows: https://www.digicert.com/util/

If had the capability to generate certificate requests. It will also convert certificates between different formats