# making CSR certificates in Windows (7)

Tags: ios, windows-7, ssl, csr, provisioning-profile

Closely related to [How to generate CSR when IIS is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468741/windows-7-how-to-generate-csr-when-iis-is-not-installed).

I also do not have this installed. I am developing a mobile application for iOS, and i am trying to obtain a provisioning file so i can test my app locally. In the process of acquiring this, i am asked for a `.csr` file, and it instructs me on how to build this on my Mac. Except i don't have a mac, i have a PC, and my company exclusively uses PCs. I need this certificate, without having access to a Mac.

i have seen and used [this](http://www.gogetssl.com/eng/support/online_csr_generator/) CSR generator, but it gives me the key and request in long strings of characters, and i need a `.csr` file to upload to Apple.

Pasting it in notepad and changing the extension to .csr didn't work either :/

Does anyone have any insights on this?

Comment: Most likely you get base64-encoded CSR. So you should decode it to get binary data. It's strange (from a common sense point of view, not strange for Apple though) that base64-encoded CSRs are not supported.

Comment: Search google for "how to base64 decode data on Windows"?

Comment: i don't think the encoding is the problem, the problem is it didn't give me a file, it just gave me the text strings.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it was file or a text string. The fact is that this text string is most likely base64-encoded certificate request in PKCS#10 format.

Comment: the problem is that i have a text string, but i need to upload a .certSigningRequest to Apple. Don't worry about it though, i just borrowed a Mac to bring to work today and got it done :)

Comment: Came here for using IIS which seems to require a password-protected PFX private key for the website for a next step.  I know the question isn't about IIS and @EwyynTomato has a create answer for generating the CSR, but for the PFX if anyone needs it you can use instructions on [this page](https://langui.sh/2009/01/24/generating-a-pkcs12-pfx-via-openssl/): `openssl pkcs12 --export -in my.cer -inkey my.key -out mycert.pfx`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can install [OpenSSL for windows](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) and generate CSR file with this command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private_key.key -out cer_sign_request.csr
```

You'll be asked for a few questions which are optional (press ENTER).

This will generate a private key (such in keychain access) and a certification signing request as csr file.

Comment: Be aware that apple only supports RSA keys with a length of 2048. All others are rejected in the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks for that note, Apple's info seemed to confirm that 2048 is the right length, and it worked for me now, so edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want an easy to use graphical interface, Digicert has a ["Digicert Utility"](https://www.digicert.com/util) that is pretty solid. You can use it to create a CSR. It doesnt give you back a private key, so you need to import your self signed or CA certificate to complete the installation of the certificate. Once installed, you can export it as a pfx or crt/key bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf
```

if saved in c:\openssl

You can download this example fileopenssl-dem-server-cert-thvs.cnf

```
rename openssl

ren cert-thvs.cnf openssl.cnf
```