# Generate Certificate Signing Request from ASP.NET web api self host machine(no IIS installed yet)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl

I'm using Windows server 2012 with my application run with ASP.NET WEB API 2 by self-host mode.

I'm trying to move all my services to https based, before buying a certificate, I need submit the ***Certificate Signing Request***, from the vendor's documentation, the generating is started from a web host application, like Apache, IIS 6, IIS 7 and etc.

so what I supposed to do? Install the **IIS** though I won't use it or ?

thanks.

Comment: OpenSSL is your friend. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186368 (ignore the accepted answer because it's junk). See also: http://luke.breuer.com/time/item/Generating_an_SSL_certificate_on_Windows_without_IIS/634.aspx

Comment: @Kev oh, so basically there's nothing to do with the Web server, a standalone command line will do everything.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. All IIS gives you is a convenient UI, the CSR itself isn't locked to IIS in any way.